# problem with ubuntu 14.04 videos

Tags: 14.04

I have both ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7 installed on my computer. ubuntu videos worked fine after the installation.

However, after I booted windows, it check the disk for errors. Now I boot ubuntu again, video did not work properly. Each time I drag the slider, it crashes. I tried VLC. Same problem. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: What video player are you using?

Comment: It just called "Videos", integrated in 14.04

Comment: That is `totem`. Install VLC with `sudo apt-get install vlc` and check if the problem persists.

Comment: I tried VLC. Same problem

Comment: Have you tried playing a file that wasn't on the drive you checked for errors?

Comment: how to check then?

Comment: Try opening the Additional Drivers utility (Dash -> Additional Drivers) and check if there is an additional driver available that has (proprietary, tested) appearing after it.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that when I had only 2 partitions, one for Windows and one for Linux, and had all my Movies/Music/etc. on the windows partition, the Windows Check Disk would render those files unplayable in Linux.

My solution  was to make THREE partitions, the first one for Windows, the one in the middle as a shared NTFS drive that both Windows and Linux can access, and the last partition on the drive I put Linux onto.

Having all these partitions means that when you boot to windows and it checks the disk for errors, windows will check only it's own partition, leaving the rest alone. With all the movies/etc. on another partition, they are left alone.

Hope this helps!